# Gather scattered values in a Web-Control from code-behind & add values to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

Here's a scenario.

[image: UI]

I have a 5 rows and 3 columns table having Textboxes in the UI. The values of each row may or may not be entered. Consider a possibility that all the values in the 5*3 tables are entered, so in code-behind i need to capture those values, bind it in a control(may be list control or an Array or Datarow) and make the loop to be iterated so as i can add values to the DB.

The loop concept is there for the sake - if a user didn't enter values in all the columns. How should i accomplish this??

P.S. - I am inserting those values in the Database afterwords.

Answer (score 0):

Use DataTable
Add rows and then add them in the grid. iterate loop through Gridview rows.